# Write data from multiple input CSV file to a single CSV in column format

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I'm trying to

- loop over multiple csv files,
- extract information from them
- write an output into one new csv file with a row for each of the
  original files.

I take the information:

> Name, Date, Time, Test, Navg, Percent

for each row.

I have tried to do it, however I have the problems:

1. It writes each of Name, Date, Time, Test, Navg, Percent to a NEW ROW...I want each word in a new column
2. It writes each new file to the a new row underneath(I do want it underneath, but with each word in a column.

   ```
   b = open('C:\Users\AClayton\Desktop\Data.csv', 'a')
   a = csv.writer(b,delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n')
   a.writerows((Name, Date, Time, Test, Navg, Percent))
   b.close()
   ```

Note the file has been read and the data extracted in earlier code.

Comment: Please don't add text like "[Python]" to your question's title - tagging the question correctly is sufficient.

Comment: You need `writerow()` instead of `writerows()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writerows` interpretes the input argument as a list of rows, hence each item in your tuple is written into a separate row.
Using `writerow` should write it into a single row.

Comment: thanks, Sebastian, it's half way there. However, I would like to put each in a new cell in the csv. At the moment it is all in one cell

Comment: ahh changed the delimiter to a comma and it worked perfectly :)